# open file dialog in android using Qt

Tags: android, qt

What's the best way to choice (select/open) file using Qt in Android ?
I'm tried to use QFileDialog But did not get good result , Is there anyway to use android native open file dialog in Qt ?!﻿

Answer (score 0):

In Qt 5.3, the Qt Quick Controls look good but they don’t (yet) look the same as Android’s Java Controls. This is something that’s planned to be fixed for Qt 5.4.

You can use Ministro to have Native look in your app :

- Switch to Projects mode
- Select the Run Settings for Android
- Open Deploy configurations Details
- Select Use Ministro service to install Qt

Now the Qt Widgets will have a native Android look. But there is a big drawback: Your App has now a dependency to the Ministro App. The App will check on startup if Ministro is installed on your device. If it is not installed the user is forced to install it over the Android Play Store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not a good idea. I'm trying to make my own file dialog...